# How to import Excel's serialized datetime into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, datetime, serialization

How do I import and preserve date format fields such as "8/21/2012" from Excel to MySQL?

I am using MySQL Workbench and the Excel MySQL Excel data transfer plug in. When I select the Excel data I want to import into MySQL, I get a window where I declare variable types for all fields. All fields and declarations work as expected except for date and time fields. Both date and time switch from 8/21/2012 to a number like 398475 etc. How can I import these fields into MySQL by preserving the dashed mm/dd/yyyy format? I assume the same procedure will work for time as well.

Alternatively, is there a way to convert the serialized datetime value (a float, representing the number of days since 1/1/1900) back to mm/dd/yyyy in MySQL ?

Thank you!

Comment: The way a database stores date-time data is commonly *not* the way the information is displayed to you. Often a date or time is a number of seconds, milliseconds, or nanoseconds since an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). You need to study up on the [date-time data types in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html), how they are stored, and how they behave. The SQL standard defines a few such data types, but databases often extend those types or define more such types.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your date cells into a MySQL supported format using the [TEXT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) function.

```
=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

This will convert a date in cell `A1` to the `yyyy-mm-dd` format that the MySQL [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) field expects.

Answer (score 2):

To get the serialized date format (say 36422) into a useful date format in MYSQL use the interval function added to the base date that Excel uses (which is actually 1900-00-00 but since that doesn't exist you will have to use 1900-01-01 which is why we subtract 2 from the date column)

```
`'1900-01-01' + INTERVAL(Your_Date_Column - 2)DAY`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your datetime cells into a MySQL supported format using the TEXT function

`=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")`

Answer (score -1):

Simply use Date (java.util package)  for this.

**Date d=Date date=cell.getDateCellValue();**

Now Use it as you want.

Comment: If you are using MysqlforExcel tool then you have to format cell of excel sheet before you import. Right click on the cell containing Date (in excel) and then click on format cell, Now select an appropriate format.